# excel fill cells between two the same cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that looks like below:

```
A1 Sometext1
A2         0
A3 Sometext1
A4 Someothertext2
A5         0
A6         0
A7 Someothertext2
```

I want to fill gaps between two the same cells with that text itself (like below). How do I do that? I've tried few ideas I had but none of them worked.

```
A1 Sometext1
A2 Sometext1
A3 Sometext1
A4 Someothertext2
A5 Someothertext2
A6 Someothertext2
A7 Someothertext2
```

Comment: Please, show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It returns in column D:D, just in order to check if the returned array is what you need:

```
Sub FillTheSameString()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, strTheSame As String, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("B1:B" & lastR).Value
  
  strTheSame = arr(1, 1)
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr) - 1
    If arr(i, 1) = strTheSame Then
        strTheSame = arr(i + 1, 1): i = i + 1
    Else
        arr(i, 1) = strTheSame
    End If
  Next i
  sh.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = arr
End Sub
```

If the code returns what you want, please change `sh.Range("D1").Resize...` with `sh.Range("B1").Resize...`.